# How can I import Excel file in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a code in which I can import .CSV file in my mysql. But I can not import Excel file. Some garbage values insert in my database while I import Excel file.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
//First we need to make a connection with the database
include("connection.php");
echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
{
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
//$sql_data = "SELECT * FROM prod_list_1 ";
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
//print_r($emapData);
//exit();
$sql = "INSERT into city(city_id,city_name) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
fclose($file);
echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
header('Location: index.php');
}
else
echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
}
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
<p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you had a close look at your Excel csv file? Sometimes there are multi-line cells in Excel that cause trouble.

Comment: Can you show samples for `garbage values`?

Comment: In my excel file only 2 Columns Like City Id, City Name. Garbage values is like ÐÏà¡±á, ÂCalib, õÿ ôÀ à

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to read an excel file using some code that is able to parse only csv files, you can't, the format is *completely* different.

Check for filetype and use a library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) if the user sends you an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com) to import Excel file and than to insert data into MySQL database:

```
$workbook = new COM("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument");
$rows = $workbook->easy_ReadXLSActiveSheet_AsList($filename);
```

For more details see this link about [importing Excel file to MySQL using EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/import-excel-to-mysql.html).