# Import Excel file in to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I need to upload excel file in to mysql db, i can upload csv, but excel file not uploading properly

here is my code

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$c = 0;
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
$c++;                                
if($c>1){                                 
$sql = "INSERT into `table`(`name`,`email`) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]')";
mysql_query($sql);
}                                             
}
if($sql){
echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ."     recoreds";
}else{
echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php)

Comment: Check my answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018419/how-can-i-import-excel-file-in-mysql/31023921#31023921

Answer (score -1):

You need to use PHPExcel library for access to excel file.